# Reference another model in mongoose schema using Nest.js

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I'm just starting out with Nest.js and I'm having some trouble understanding why I can't reference a mongoose model in other mongoose schema.

It works fine for the Unit model, just not the  Product.

Here's my code for a reference:

**ProductUnit Schema**

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, SchemaTypes } from 'mongoose';
import { Product } from 'src/products/entities/product.entity';
import { Unit } from 'src/units/entities/unit.entity';

@Schema()
export class ProductUnit extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: Unit.name })
  unit: Unit;

  @Prop({ type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: Product.name })
  product: Product;

  @Prop({ default: false })
  defaultBuy: boolean;

  @Prop({ default: false })
  defaultSell: boolean;
}

export const ProductUnitSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(ProductUnit);
```

**ProductUnits Module**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ProductsModule } from 'src/products/products.module';
import { UnitsModule } from 'src/units/units.module';
import { ProductUnit, ProductUnitSchema } from './entities/product-unit.entity';
import { ProductUnitsService } from './product-units.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: ProductUnit.name,
        schema: ProductUnitSchema,
      },
    ]),
    UnitsModule,
    ProductsModule,
  ],
  providers: [ProductUnitsService],
  exports: [ProductUnitsService],
})
export class ProductUnitsModule {}
```

**Products Module**

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: Product.name,
        schema: ProductSchema,
      },
    ]),
    TagsModule,
    ProductUnitsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [ProductsController],
  providers: [
    ProductsService,
    IsTagValidator,
    IsCategoryValidator,
    ProductUnitsService,
  ],
  exports: [ProductsService],
})
export class ProductsModule {}
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the my application:

```
/mnt/c/Users/***/Documents/codespace/FullPOS/fullpos/dist/products/entities/product.entity.js:41
    mongoose_1.Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose_2.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: product_unit_entity_1.ProductUnit.name }] }),

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/***/Documents/codespace/FullPOS/fullpos/dist/products/entities/product.entity.js:41:110)        
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
```

This is catching me off guard since I'm doing the same thing with other mongoose schemas, and it works fine.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was also dealing with the same issue. I solved it by passing schema(collection) name as String like ref: 'Product' instead of ref: Product.name

I know this solution compromises on type safety here, but this seems to be the only solution. Anyone else has a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, Here the reason for error is: In the Schema of 'ProductUnit' U are referring the schema of 'Product'. That means you tried to ref 'Product' from 'ProductUnit' and 'ProductUnit' from 'Product'